# Authentication on google api (calendar) with flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to retrieve events from google calendar api using

```
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart' as calendarapi;
```

...

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(
    {
    "private_key_id": "562ab...",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--............----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1073.......",
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "myapi"
   }
  );

  final scopes = [calendarapi.CalendarApi.CalendarScope];
  final client = new http.Client();
 

  void getCalendarEvents() { 
      clientViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes).then((client) {
        var calendar = new calendarapi.CalendarApi(client);
        var calEvents = calendar.events.list("primary");
        calEvents.then((calendarapi.Events events) {
          events.items.forEach((calendarapi.Event event) {print(event.summary);});
        });
          client.close();
      });
  }
}
```

...

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCalendarEvents();
  }
```

The line clientViaServiceAccount throws an exception

> FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected end of input)

The credentials should be fine because I already use them in a different client. In fiddler there is no outgoing traffic so it looks like there is an error even before the request gets send. Whats wrong in the code?

**EDIT**

This is the stack of the error

> > ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> > FormatException was thrown running a test: Unexpected end of input
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1392:5)
> #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:510:7)
> #2      _JsonStringDecoderSink.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1487:13)
> #3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:80:18)
> #15     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:249:11)
> #16     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:300:20)
> #17     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:80:18)
> #46     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:855:25)
> #49     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
> #50     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:840:27)
> #51     WidgetTester.pumpWidget. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:318:22)
> #54     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
> #55     WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:315:27)
> #56     main. (file:///C:/projekte/flutter_garden/flutter_garden/test/widget_test.dart:9:18)
> #58     main. (file:///C:/projekte/flutter_garden/flutter_garden/test/widget_test.dart:7:43)
> #59     testWidgets.. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:119:25)
> #61     testWidgets.. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:117:9)
> #62     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:648:19)
> #76     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1032:17)
> #78     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1020:35) (elided 74 frames from
> class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and
> package stack_trace)

Comment: I don't know if you copied the whole code but what I could see right away is that there is no closing bracket for the class ` _MyHomePageState`, you might want to check on that. If I understood correctly your code is not even executing? Or is the error part of the client getting to the google server. I would say that you already did but if not read [the following page](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth), in there is recommended to `close` the client after the interaction.

Comment: I updated the  code. client.close() did not change the outcome. getCalendarEvents is called within initState

Comment: But is your code even executing/compiling? Do you have a way to check if you are making the request to google servers?

Comment: Yes I run the code via a flutter unittest an it is hitting getCalendarEvents -> clientViaServiceAccount

Comment: excuse me, could you tell me how to get my accountCredentials JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code via the emulator and not from the unittests fixed the problem.